# Не работает считыватель в режиме клавиатуры

Tags: windows, usb

Я использую считыватель HID Omnikey 5427 CK и при переходе в режим KBW система(Windows) перестает его видеть, в диспетчере устройств отображается как HID-устройство ввода с ошибкой "Код 10 Запуск устройства невозможен", CDC EEM драйвер тоже не видится считывателем, следовательно я не могу зайти в веб интерфейс и как-то его настроить. В режиме CCID считыватель виден системой, но EEM драйвер все равно не работает. Пробовал подключать считыватель к MacOS, там работает в обоих режимах, но EEM драйверов нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, как я решил эту проблему?
Магическим образом из 7 пк на разных версиях винды + из нескольких образах виртуальной машины считыватель заработал на одном пк, на котором стояла 7 винда с драйверами от множества разных считывателей, начиная с iron logic и заканчивая неизвестными мне представителями данной отрасли.
Я поставил CDC EEM драйвера и через веб-интерфейс сбросил все настройки фильтрации id карт к заводским, после чего перезагрузил считыватель и он стал работать на всех остальных пк в штатном режиме.
Проще говоря, если у вас не работает HID Omnikey 5427 CK, то подключайте его к различным пк с мешаниной драйверов и надейтесь на удачу!